# nested JAVAFX applications running services

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, service, javafx

after creating multiple objects extending JavaFX's application object, i wanted to incorporate some of them under one full UI. so i created another object extending "application", created instances of each little app, called their "start" method and used a method i created in each little application to retrieve it's root node to the full UI application. i then added these into the full UI scene and all of them were presented in that one GUI.
problem is some are static and some actually work as expected. all of the little apps have services which they run and update their ui from time to time using platform.runlater.
but only some actually update. i've tried canceling some of them and then those which didn't work suddenly work. 
why are those services not running?
is there a restriction on the amount of threads?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html) object is created by the JavaFX Runtime and there should only be one instance per `Application`, as it is a `Process`.

If what you are trying to accomplish is having multiple windows, you should create multiple `Scene`, not multiple `Application`.

[This question covers the basics of creating multiple scenes and why you shouldn't have more instances of Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653118/javafx-launch-another-application)

Comment: well actually i found out it was a resources problem. when i gave it some more CPU and memory it worked.
but now i see that it only works through eclipse. if i create a runnable jar it works very slowly.