# JavaFX integration with Spring rest client

Tags: java, rest, javafx, javafx-webengine

i have implemented Java Spring Rest client application, each rest am geting input xml file , and taxking that file according file values am select jsp file showing in Javafx Webview, once ur transaction completed i need to close that webview window. send back result  as rest clinet response. for every request i need to open javafx webview winodow and process it.

but here am faceing onec issues.

Rest cleint Call

```
static String url ="http://localhost:8080/login.jsp?value=47&key=645";
    javafx.application.Application.launch(Webview.class);
```

Webview class

```
public class Webview extends Application {

    public static Stage stage;
    public static WebView view;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage _stage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Start");
        stage = _stage;
        Platform.setImplicitExit(true);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        view = new WebView();

        WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();
        engine.load(PaymentServerRestAPI.BROWSER_URL);
        root.getChildren().add(view);
        engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);



        stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent arg0) {

                Platform.exit();
            }
        });

        JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
        window.setMember("app", new BrowserApp());

        stage.show();

    }

}
```

//JavaScript interface object

```
public class BrowserApp {



    public void exit() {
        System.out.println("exist calling button");
        Browser.frame.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

problem is one request successful completed next request am getting 
 "ERROR IN MAIN:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more
 than once".
how to handle this. any other way to handle this problem ,thanks

Comment: Can you refer to this SO Q&A? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653118/javafx-launch-another-application

Comment: @Octopus i have seen this but my case rest client call javafx application once process it send back as response and close that window.