# Is there a way to open a JavaFX Application within another Application?

Tags: java, javafx

I have two classes : 
One is called "Game" and it extends Application. Running this will launch the video game I've created.
The other is called LocalClient, it also extends Application. Running this will give me a Menu, giving me the option to open the game by the press of a button.
The problem is that I don't want to open the game, I just want to render both Applications in the same Frame

```
public class LocalClient extends Application {

    Pane root;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
// my start method for LocalClient
}

private class GameMenu extends Parent {
// this is another class where i have my buttons and the different menus/submenus
}


public class Game extends Application {

    private Pane root = new Pane();
    private Level level; // level is an abstract class I use

    /**
     * Stars the game and begins rendering
     * @param stage stage to render all objects to
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
// my Start mmethod for the game
```

Comment: This seems like very strange design. Why not have just one application that runs both the client and the game?

Comment: I am working with a team and we got to different aspects of the project separately. The game works, however we'd like to make it look more united

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to run one JavaFX application within the window of another. But something like this should definitely be just one application. Whatever UI was designed for the game portion could easily be placed within a pane in the main Client application window...

Comment: Not sure if this is 100% a duplicate, but an approach is presented in the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653118/javafx-launch-another-application

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, I am already able to launch an application from within another. What I want to do is to possibly "combine" them

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `main(String[] args)` method, instead of using `launch(args);`, you can use `Game.launch(args);`.  Then, inside the `start()` method in your `Game` class, type `LocalClient.launch(args);`.